# How to average list elements in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `L`. I want to average elements of each list within this list. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
L=[[], [1.3342713788981633], [1.3342713788981633], [0.40896852187708455,1,3]]
L_avg=[(i+j)/len[i,j] for [i,j] in L]
print(L_avg)
```

The error is

```
in <listcomp>
    L_avg=[(i+j)/len[i,j] for [i,j] in L]

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

The expected output is

```
L_avg=[[], [1.3342713788981633], [1.3342713788981633], [(0.40896852187708455+1+3)/3]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because of this:

```py
for [i,j] in L
```

In this way you are trying to assign elements of `L` to `[i,j]` but expressions such as  `[i,j]=[]` or `[i,j]=[1.3342713788981633]` just make no sense.

Here's what you should do instead

```py
L=[[], [1.3342713788981633], [1.3342713788981633], [0.40896852187708455,1,3]]

L_avg = [
    [sum(x)/len(x)] if x else [] for x in L
]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```py
L_avg=[sum(sublist)/len(sublist) if sublist else [] for sublist in L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
L=[[], [1.3342713788981633], [1.3342713788981633], [0.40896852187708455,1,3]]

L_avg = [ sum(l)/len(l) if len(l) > 0 else [] for l in L ]

print(L_avg)
```

Explanation: this iterates over all the sublists in `L` and calculates the average as the sum of the elements over the number of elements. The `if-else` is necessary to handle the case when the sublist is empty, which would give a division by 0.

Answer (score 0):

You only be able to do this averaging if all your list members have values inside, in your case the first is empty, hence the error. It expected 2 parameters and got 0.

You can filter out the ones with len zero:

```
L_avg = [sum(item)/len(item) if len(item)>0 else []  for item in L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think about how to do this in a for loop it'll make it easier to understand a comprehension.

```py
for sl in L:
    print(sum(sl)/len(sl) if sl > 0 else [])
```

So the comprehension is:

```py
[sum(sl)/len(sl) if sl > 0 else [] for sl in L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
L_avg = [sum(l)/len(l) if len(l)>0 else [] for l in L]
```

it would probably make more sense to return `None` instead of `[]` when the list on computing the average is empty:

```
L_avg = [sum(l)/len(l) if len(l)>0 else None for l in L]
```